# How could I preview an image without storing in aws s3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, vuejs2

My question is: Should I create 2 folders: one for temporary and another one for original? I'm using a component for uploading images. When I upload an image, It is stored in s3 and it is retrieved again to be shown in a small image.  My problem here is If I upload 1 image and then I decide to upload another one, I uploaded 2 files in the S3 bucket and so on ... without pressing add category.
Finally: I'm using Vue 2 and Laravel 7.x, thanks.

I'm not so familiar with storing process but I need help to decide what is more efficient, thanks.

**category.vue**

```js
<template>
  <Modal v-model="addModal" :closable="false" :mask-closable="false" title="Add a category">
    <Input v-model="data.categoryName" placeholder="Add category..."/>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <Upload ref="uploads" action="/app/upload" :format="['jpg','jpeg','png']" :
            headers="{'x-csrf-token': token, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}" :max-size="2048"
            :on-error="handleError" :on-exceeded-size="handleMaxSize" :on-format-error="handleFormatError"
            :on-success="handleSuccess" type="drag">
      <div style="padding: 20px 0">
        <Icon size="52" style="color: #3399ff" type="ios-cloud-upload"></Icon>
        <p> Click or drag files here to upload </p>
      </div>
    </Upload>

    <div v-if="data.iconImage" class="demo-upload-list">
      <img :src="`${data.iconImage}`"/>
      <div class="demo-upload-list-cover">
        <Icon type="ios-trash-outline" @click="deleteImage"></Icon>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div slot="footer">
      <Button type="default" @click="addModal=false">Close</Button>
      <Button :disabled="isAdding" :loading="isAdding" type="primary" @click="addCategory">
        {{ isAdding ? 'Adding ..' : 'Add a category' }}
      </Button>
    </div>
  </Modal>
</template>

<script>
// Other parts of this section are removed for clarity
export default {
  methods: {
    async addCategory() {
      console.log('1', this.data.iconImage)
      if (this.data.categoryName.trim() === '') return this.e('This Category is required')
      if (this.data.iconImage.trim() === '') return this.e('This Icon Image is required')


      this.data.iconImage = `${this.data.iconImage}`
      console.log('2', this.data.iconImage)


      const res = await this.callApi('post', 'app/create_category', this.data)

      if (res.status === 200) {
        this.categoryLists.unshift(res.data)
        this.s('Category has been succesfully')
        this.addModal = false
        this.data.categoryName = ''
        this.data.iconImage = ''
        this.$refs.uploads.clearFiles()
      } else {
        if (res.status === 422) {
          if (res.data.errors.categoryName) {
            this.e(res.data.errors.categoryName[0])
          }
          if (res.data.errors.iconImage) {
            this.e(res.data.errors.iconImage[0])
          }
        } else {
          this.swr()
        }
      }
    },
  },
}

</script>
```

**My controller for addCategory**

```php
public function addCategory(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'categoryName' => 'required',
        'iconImage'    => 'required',
    ]);

    $category = new Category();

    $category->categoryName = $request->categoryName;
    $category->iconImage = $request->iconImage;

    $category->save();

    return response()->json($category);
}
```

Comment: Use something like [filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) which also has a [Vue adapter](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/getting-started/installation/vue/) and has the facility to display images during the upload process.

Comment: I was following the documentation but It seems the this plugin doesn't include a component after being installed